# Retrieve extension_attributes with API searchCriteria working wrong

Tags: magento2, api, extension-attributes, search-criteria

I created a new field on Creditmemos as an extension_attribute.

I thought is working fine, when I create a Creditmemo, the field is saved correctly in the ddbb and when I get the creditmemo with the API: `/rest/V1/creditmemo/6` it displays correctly too.

But then I tested using `/rest/V1/creditmemos?searchCriteria=0` and is doing something weird... my attribute extension is always returning the same value for every creditmemo. Is that a bug? How can I solve that?

I post my code for the context of retrieving the value:

`etc/extension_attributes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoInterface">
        <attribute code="size_exchange" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

`etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_creditmemo_save_after">
        <observer name="creditmemo_save_size_exchange" instance="vendor\module\Observer\SaveExchangeCreditmemo"/>
    </event>
    <event name="sales_order_creditmemo_load_after">
        <observer name="creditmemo_load_size_exchange" instance="vendor\module\Observer\LoadExchangeCreditmemo"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

`Observer/LoadExchangeCreditmemo.php`

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoExtension;

class LoadExchangeCreditmemo implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $field = 'size_exchange';
    private $creditmemoExtension;


    public function __construct(CreditmemoExtension $creditmemoExtension)
    {
        $this->creditmemoExtension = $creditmemoExtension;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $creditmemo = $observer->getCreditmemo();
        $extensionAttributes = $creditmemo->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->creditmemoExtension;
        }

        $value = $creditmemo->getData($this->field) ? $creditmemo->getData($this->field) : '0';
        $extensionAttributes->setData($this->field, $value);

        $creditmemo->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
    }
}
```

**Results**

`V1/creditmemos?searchCriteria=0`

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "adjustment": 0,
      "base_adjustment": 0,
      "base_currency_code": "USD",
      "base_discount_amount": 0,
      "base_grand_total": 7.64,
      "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "base_shipping_amount": 5,
      "base_shipping_incl_tax": 5,
      "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_subtotal": 0,
      "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_tax_amount": 2.64,
      "base_to_global_rate": 1,
      "base_to_order_rate": 1,
      "billing_address_id": 4,
      "created_at": "2017-05-04 09:20:00",
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "entity_id": 1,
      "global_currency_code": "USD",
      "grand_total": 7.64,
      "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "increment_id": "000000001",
      "order_currency_code": "USD",
      "order_id": 2,
      "shipping_address_id": 3,
      "shipping_amount": 5,
      "shipping_incl_tax": 5,
      "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "state": 2,
      "store_currency_code": "USD",
      "store_id": 1,
      "store_to_base_rate": 0,
      "store_to_order_rate": 0,
      "subtotal": 0,
      "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "tax_amount": 2.64,
      "updated_at": "2017-05-04 09:20:00",
      "items": [
        {
          "base_cost": null,
          "base_price": 0,
          "base_row_total": 0,
          "base_weee_tax_row_disposition": 0,
          "entity_id": 1,
          "name": "Minerva LumaTech&trade; V-Tee-XS-Blue",
          "order_item_id": 2,
          "parent_id": 1,
          "price": 0,
          "product_id": 1483,
          "qty": 1,
          "row_total": 0,
          "sku": "WS08-XS-Blue",
          "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
          "weee_tax_applied_row_amount": 0,
          "weee_tax_row_disposition": 0
        }
      ],
      "comments": [],
      "extension_attributes": {
        "size_exchange": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "adjustment": 0,
      "adjustment_negative": 0,
      "adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_adjustment": 0,
      "base_adjustment_negative": 0,
      "base_adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_currency_code": "USD",
      "base_discount_amount": 0,
      "base_grand_total": 7.39,
      "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "base_shipping_amount": 5,
      "base_shipping_incl_tax": 5,
      "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_subtotal": 0,
      "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_tax_amount": 2.39,
      "base_to_global_rate": 1,
      "base_to_order_rate": 1,
      "billing_address_id": 2,
      "created_at": "2017-05-04 20:16:59",
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "entity_id": 3,
      "global_currency_code": "USD",
      "grand_total": 7.39,
      "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "increment_id": "000000003",
      "order_currency_code": "USD",
      "order_id": 1,
      "shipping_address_id": 1,
      "shipping_amount": 5,
      "shipping_incl_tax": 5,
      "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "state": 2,
      "store_currency_code": "USD",
      "store_id": 1,
      "store_to_base_rate": 0,
      "store_to_order_rate": 0,
      "subtotal": 0,
      "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "tax_amount": 2.39,
      "updated_at": "2017-05-04 20:16:59",
      "items": [
        {
          "base_cost": null,
          "base_price": 0,
          "base_row_total": 0,
          "base_weee_tax_row_disposition": 0,
          "entity_id": 2,
          "name": "Iris Workout Top-XS-Red",
          "order_item_id": 1,
          "parent_id": 3,
          "price": 0,
          "product_id": 1420,
          "qty": 1,
          "row_total": 0,
          "sku": "WS03-XS-Red",
          "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
          "weee_tax_applied_row_amount": 0,
          "weee_tax_row_disposition": 0
        }
      ],
      "comments": [],
      "extension_attributes": {
        "size_exchange": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "adjustment": 0,
      "adjustment_negative": 0,
      "adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_adjustment": 0,
      "base_adjustment_negative": 0,
      "base_adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_currency_code": "USD",
      "base_discount_amount": 0,
      "base_grand_total": 45.47,
      "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "base_shipping_amount": 0,
      "base_shipping_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_subtotal": 42,
      "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 45.47,
      "base_tax_amount": 3.47,
      "base_to_global_rate": 1,
      "base_to_order_rate": 1,
      "billing_address_id": 6,
      "created_at": "2017-05-04 20:19:22",
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "entity_id": 4,
      "global_currency_code": "USD",
      "grand_total": 45.47,
      "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "increment_id": "000000004",
      "order_currency_code": "USD",
      "order_id": 3,
      "shipping_address_id": 5,
      "shipping_amount": 0,
      "shipping_incl_tax": 0,
      "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "state": 2,
      "store_currency_code": "USD",
      "store_id": 1,
      "store_to_base_rate": 0,
      "store_to_order_rate": 0,
      "subtotal": 42,
      "subtotal_incl_tax": 45.47,
      "tax_amount": 3.47,
      "updated_at": "2017-05-04 20:19:22",
      "items": [
        {
          "base_cost": null,
          "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
          "base_price": 21,
          "base_price_incl_tax": 22.74,
          "base_row_total": 42,
          "base_row_total_incl_tax": 45.47,
          "base_tax_amount": 3.47,
          "base_weee_tax_row_disposition": 0,
          "entity_id": 3,
          "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
          "name": "Sprite Yoga Strap 10 foot",
          "order_item_id": 3,
          "parent_id": 4,
          "price": 21,
          "price_incl_tax": 22.74,
          "product_id": 35,
          "qty": 2,
          "row_total": 42,
          "row_total_incl_tax": 45.47,
          "sku": "24-WG087",
          "tax_amount": 3.47,
          "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
          "weee_tax_applied_row_amount": 0,
          "weee_tax_row_disposition": 0
        }
      ],
      "comments": [],
      "extension_attributes": {
        "size_exchange": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "adjustment": 0,
      "adjustment_negative": 0,
      "adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_adjustment": 0,
      "base_adjustment_negative": 0,
      "base_adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_currency_code": "USD",
      "base_discount_amount": 0,
      "base_grand_total": 1,
      "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "base_shipping_amount": 1,
      "base_shipping_incl_tax": 1,
      "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_subtotal": 0,
      "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_to_global_rate": 1,
      "base_to_order_rate": 1,
      "billing_address_id": 6,
      "created_at": "2017-05-04 20:24:44",
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "entity_id": 7,
      "global_currency_code": "USD",
      "grand_total": 1,
      "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "increment_id": "000000007",
      "order_currency_code": "USD",
      "order_id": 3,
      "shipping_address_id": 5,
      "shipping_amount": 1,
      "shipping_incl_tax": 1,
      "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "state": 2,
      "store_currency_code": "USD",
      "store_id": 1,
      "store_to_base_rate": 0,
      "store_to_order_rate": 0,
      "subtotal": 0,
      "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "tax_amount": 0,
      "updated_at": "2017-05-04 20:24:44",
      "items": [],
      "comments": [],
      "extension_attributes": {
        "size_exchange": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "adjustment": 0,
      "adjustment_negative": 0,
      "adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_adjustment": 0,
      "base_adjustment_negative": 0,
      "base_adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_currency_code": "USD",
      "base_discount_amount": 0,
      "base_grand_total": 1,
      "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "base_shipping_amount": 1,
      "base_shipping_incl_tax": 1,
      "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_subtotal": 0,
      "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_to_global_rate": 1,
      "base_to_order_rate": 1,
      "billing_address_id": 6,
      "created_at": "2017-05-04 20:32:40",
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "entity_id": 15,
      "global_currency_code": "USD",
      "grand_total": 1,
      "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "increment_id": "000000015",
      "order_currency_code": "USD",
      "order_id": 3,
      "shipping_address_id": 5,
      "shipping_amount": 1,
      "shipping_incl_tax": 1,
      "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "state": 2,
      "store_currency_code": "USD",
      "store_id": 1,
      "store_to_base_rate": 0,
      "store_to_order_rate": 0,
      "subtotal": 0,
      "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "tax_amount": 0,
      "updated_at": "2017-05-04 20:32:40",
      "items": [],
      "comments": [],
      "extension_attributes": {
        "size_exchange": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "adjustment": 0,
      "adjustment_negative": 0,
      "adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_adjustment": 0,
      "base_adjustment_negative": 0,
      "base_adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_currency_code": "USD",
      "base_discount_amount": 0,
      "base_grand_total": 1,
      "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "base_shipping_amount": 1,
      "base_shipping_incl_tax": 1,
      "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_subtotal": 0,
      "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_to_global_rate": 1,
      "base_to_order_rate": 1,
      "billing_address_id": 6,
      "created_at": "2017-05-04 20:33:00",
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "entity_id": 16,
      "global_currency_code": "USD",
      "grand_total": 1,
      "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "increment_id": "000000016",
      "order_currency_code": "USD",
      "order_id": 3,
      "shipping_address_id": 5,
      "shipping_amount": 1,
      "shipping_incl_tax": 1,
      "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "state": 2,
      "store_currency_code": "USD",
      "store_id": 1,
      "store_to_base_rate": 0,
      "store_to_order_rate": 0,
      "subtotal": 0,
      "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "tax_amount": 0,
      "updated_at": "2017-05-04 20:33:00",
      "items": [],
      "comments": [],
      "extension_attributes": {
        "size_exchange": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "adjustment": 0,
      "adjustment_negative": 0,
      "adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_adjustment": 0,
      "base_adjustment_negative": 0,
      "base_adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_currency_code": "USD",
      "base_discount_amount": 0,
      "base_grand_total": 1,
      "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "base_shipping_amount": 1,
      "base_shipping_incl_tax": 1,
      "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_subtotal": 0,
      "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_to_global_rate": 1,
      "base_to_order_rate": 1,
      "billing_address_id": 6,
      "created_at": "2017-05-04 20:33:12",
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "entity_id": 17,
      "global_currency_code": "USD",
      "grand_total": 1,
      "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "increment_id": "000000017",
      "order_currency_code": "USD",
      "order_id": 3,
      "shipping_address_id": 5,
      "shipping_amount": 1,
      "shipping_incl_tax": 1,
      "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "state": 2,
      "store_currency_code": "USD",
      "store_id": 1,
      "store_to_base_rate": 0,
      "store_to_order_rate": 0,
      "subtotal": 0,
      "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "tax_amount": 0,
      "updated_at": "2017-05-04 20:33:12",
      "items": [],
      "comments": [],
      "extension_attributes": {
        "size_exchange": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "adjustment": 0,
      "adjustment_negative": 0,
      "adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_adjustment": 0,
      "base_adjustment_negative": 0,
      "base_adjustment_positive": 0,
      "base_currency_code": "USD",
      "base_discount_amount": 0,
      "base_grand_total": 1,
      "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "base_shipping_amount": 1,
      "base_shipping_incl_tax": 1,
      "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_subtotal": 0,
      "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_tax_amount": 0,
      "base_to_global_rate": 1,
      "base_to_order_rate": 1,
      "billing_address_id": 6,
      "created_at": "2017-05-04 21:34:12",
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "entity_id": 18,
      "global_currency_code": "USD",
      "grand_total": 1,
      "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
      "increment_id": "000000018",
      "order_currency_code": "USD",
      "order_id": 3,
      "shipping_address_id": 5,
      "shipping_amount": 1,
      "shipping_incl_tax": 1,
      "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
      "state": 2,
      "store_currency_code": "USD",
      "store_id": 1,
      "store_to_base_rate": 0,
      "store_to_order_rate": 0,
      "subtotal": 0,
      "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
      "tax_amount": 0,
      "updated_at": "2017-05-04 21:34:12",
      "items": [],
      "comments": [],
      "extension_attributes": {
        "size_exchange": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": []
  },
  "total_count": 8
}
```

`V1/creditmemo/16`

```
{
  "adjustment": 0,
  "adjustment_negative": 0,
  "adjustment_positive": 0,
  "base_adjustment": 0,
  "base_adjustment_negative": 0,
  "base_adjustment_positive": 0,
  "base_currency_code": "USD",
  "base_discount_amount": 0,
  "base_grand_total": 1,
  "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
  "base_shipping_amount": 1,
  "base_shipping_incl_tax": 1,
  "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
  "base_subtotal": 0,
  "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
  "base_tax_amount": 0,
  "base_to_global_rate": 1,
  "base_to_order_rate": 1,
  "billing_address_id": 6,
  "created_at": "2017-05-04 20:33:00",
  "discount_amount": 0,
  "entity_id": 16,
  "global_currency_code": "USD",
  "grand_total": 1,
  "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
  "increment_id": "000000016",
  "order_currency_code": "USD",
  "order_id": 3,
  "shipping_address_id": 5,
  "shipping_amount": 1,
  "shipping_incl_tax": 1,
  "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
  "state": 2,
  "store_currency_code": "USD",
  "store_id": 1,
  "store_to_base_rate": 0,
  "store_to_order_rate": 0,
  "subtotal": 0,
  "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
  "tax_amount": 0,
  "updated_at": "2017-05-04 20:33:00",
  "items": [],
  "comments": [],
  "extension_attributes": {
    "size_exchange": "0"
  }
}
```

**As you can see, when I retrieve all creditmemos, all "size_exchange" are 1, but when I get only the creditmemo with id=16, the value of that attribute is 0.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, just creating a plugin:

`etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoInterface">
    <plugin name="AddCreditmemoExtensionAttributes"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AddCreditmemoExtensionAttributes"/>
</type>
```

`Plugin/AddCreditmemoExtensionAttributes.php`

```
public function afterGetExtensionAttributes(
    CreditmemoInterface $creditmemo,
    CreditmemoExtensionInterface $extension = null
)
{
    if ($extension === null) {
        $extension = $this->extensionFactory->create();
    }

    foreach ($this->fields as $key) {
        $data = $creditmemo->getData($key) ? $creditmemo->getData($key) : '0';
        $extension->setData($key, $data);
    }

    return $extension;
}
```

And working like a charm :)

Comment: Can you specify classes for CreditmemoInterface and
    CreditmemoExtensionInterface

Comment: or please post your full plugin file. thankyou